# Subject Verb agreement: a special case?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

The sentence

- *In the play the incantations of the the witches completely accentuate/ accentuates the overall gloomy settings*.

My question is should I use the "S" at the end of the word accentuate. Whilst I know as per the the sub + verb rules the correct form should be "accentuate" but I still have confusion regarding this as the sentence doesn't really sound correct to my ear when I elide the "s" at the end. Please guide.

Comment: _Accentuate_ is correct, as you say. If it was, for example 'the noise made by the witches', _accentuates_ would be correct because _noise_ is singular.

Comment: The jarring effect I pick up is from 'completely accentuate/s', not the choice of verb form. I'd use the modifier 'greatly'.

Comment: *Why* doesn't it sound correct?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Right! The adverb "completely" would seem greatly unflattering before the word accentuate.

Comment: @Joachim  Mayhap , I am used to using sibilants a lot .

Comment: Yeah, that adjective needs to go. Accentuate is strong enough to stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

correct: **accentuate**

incantations- plural

The incantations accentuate

an incantation accentuate**s** (-s for the third person singular)

The incantation accentuate**s** (-s for the third person singular)

Comment: Hello, Mohammed. This is not a question at a suitable level for ELU.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth  What does ELU stand for ?